# What's the best way to share a dbcontext between multiple services?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, unit-of-work, transactionscope

First of all, I'm sorry if this has been answered already. But I wasn't able to find a solution.

Let's say I want to create an order along with some lines and at the same time create another entity.

Service layer:

```
public class OrderService
{
    private DbContext context;

    public OrderService()
    {
        context = new DbContext();
    }

    public void AddOrder(Order order, List<Orderline> lines, AnotherEntity anotherEntity)
    {
        context.Orders.Add(order);
        context.Orderlines.AddRange(lines);

        var anotherService = new AnotherService();
        anotherService.AddAnother(anotherEntity)

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class AnotherService
{
    private DbContext context;

    public AnotherService()
    {
        context = new DbContext();
    }

    public void AddAnother(AnotherEntity entity)
    {
        // Maybe some business rules here

        context.SomeOtherEntities.Add(entity);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
var orderService = new OrderService();
orderService.Add(order, lines, anotherEntity);
```

The first issue is that I have a different context in both services and therefore two different transactions. Solutions I can think of:

1. Pass a dbcontext from the controller through the order service to the next service. But this will expose the context to the presentation layer. And I will still have two transactions due to the SaveChanges() method in each service. I could solve this by removing the SaveChanges() in AddAnother but what if I want to call this independently from the presentation layer? Nothing will be saved then.
2. Wrap the code in AddOrder using BeginTransaction(). But what if AddAnother calls a third service and also uses BeginTransaction()? Then I will end up with multiple nested transactions.

I know about the repository/UOW pattern and even tried implementing it but I can't see how it will solve this prooblem.

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Can you explain how the other entity (i.e., `AnotherEntity`) is related to the  `Order` and the `OrderService`? Is it really the concern of the Order Service?

Comment: Why do you ever call `SaveChanges` in a service?

Comment: I can suggest a unit of work pattern. It seems this is mostly suitable in your case.

Comment: Yacoub Massad > I'm not sure I can come up with a great example right now. But let's say that AnotherEntity is a payment. So I want to create the order, some orderlines and a (pending) payment. Do you think that all of this belongs in the same service?

Comment: CodesInChaos > Where should I call it? From the client/controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use IoC container and Dependency Injection pattern in your services and whole software architecture.

```
// Simple example of MVC action method that uses injected context
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var s1 = new AnotherService(this.context);
    var s2 = new OrderService(this.context);
    // call s1 and s2 business logic

    this.context.SaveChanges();
}


public class AnotherService
{
    private DbContext context;

    public AnotherService(DbContext dbcontext)
    {
        context = dbcontext;
    }

    public void AddAnother(AnotherEntity entity)
    {
        // Maybe some business rules here

        context.SomeOtherEntities.Add(entity);

    }
}

public class OrderService
{
    private DbContext context;

    public OrderService(DbContext dbcontext)
    {
        context = dbcontext;
    }

    public void AddOrder(Order order, List<Orderline> lines, AnotherEntity anotherEntity)
    {
        context.Orders.Add(order);
        context.Orderlines.AddRange(lines);

        var anotherService = new AnotherService(context);
        anotherService.AddAnother(anotherEntity)
    }
}
```

Yes this is a simple example of usage injected DbContext but you can investigate UoW deeply [there](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

The UnitOfWork creates layer with shared instance of DbContext over your services.
As all services depends on UoW and its context then you can commit your UoW that saves data using DbContext. For instance:

```
// Simple example of MVC action method that uses injected context
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    using(var uow = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var s1 = new AnotherService(uow.Context);
        var s2 = new OrderService(uow.Context);
        // call s1 and s2 business logic
        uow.Commit();    // Commit method implements  this.context.SaveChanges();  logic.
    }
}
```

And in this implementation all your services will have the same instance of DbContext.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your last suggestion. It definitely works and it's nice not having to pass the dbcontext around, But I heard a lot of people saying that it's bad practice to let the controller know anything about UoW and/or the dbcontext. And that's why I got a little confused. Do you agree?

Comment: @netrooo  UoW is a feature that has be used in Action scoop. Usually people design UoW with Disposable interface implementation. Then use it with using declaration and Commit on Dispose. It seems ok for me to create and use in the controller. Of course you can inject UoW obj instead of DbContext into service constructor.

Comment: OK. And if I need access to service 2 from service 1, I will simply create an instance of service 2 using UoW from service 1. Is that correct?

Comment: What about query methods in the services? GetAllOrdersByCustomer, for example. I don't really need UoW and service instance in that case. Would it be wrong to make these methods static and let them use their own dbcontext?

Comment: Any thoughts on that?